# Работа с датами в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
y = datetime.time(19,00,00)
d = datetime.time(21,0,00)
x2 = x.time()
print(x.strftime("%X"))
print(y.strftime("%X"))

if (x2 >= y && x2 <= d): #здесь выдает ошибку 
    print("yes")
else:  
    print("no")
```

Как сделать, чтобы печатало "yes" когда текущее время находится между 19:00 и 21:00?

Comment: Какую ошибку? Вы не можете ее прочесть?

Answer (score 2):

В питоне логическое “и” пишется английским словом  and. Т.е. && меняете на and, всё работает

Comment: спосибо, только учусь)

Comment: @ԴաւիթՄակարեան, без проблем, если несложно, поставь галочку на ответе (это показывает, что ответ помог тебе)